# how to stop menu(top) in header

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/GuXQZ/3/ <-(my html+css code)

How to make menu stop at bottom header when scrolling down main menu stop at bottom header.
ty before for answer...

```
 body{
background: #83DF13;
font-family: Arial;
margin: auto;
}

#index{
background: #BCAEA4;
height: 35px;
padding: 0px 25px;
position: fixed;
top:0;
width: 100%;
}

/*Header Option*/
#header{
background: #fff;
width: auto;
margin: 45px 10px 10px 10px;
padding: 10px 10px;
height: 250px;
border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px; /* Old Firefox */
}

#Link{
background: #fff;
width: auto;
height: 45px;
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
-moz-border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px; /* Old Firefox */
}
```

Comment: Can you please refine your question and put it in a better fashion? I am unable to understand what you mean, though I believe I might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use js for that.

But from only css you can do like this :

http://jsfiddle.net/sachin4dotnet/GuXQZ/8/

add in css :

```
.index0{
position: relative;
}

/*Header Option*/
#header{
    z-index: 2;
}
```

and in html :

```
<div class="index0" >
    <div id="index">
    header 
    </div>
    <div id="header">
    <marquee>slideshow lates Content</marquee>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="index0" style="width: auto; z-index: 10;background: #83DF13;">
    <div style="top: auto;">
    <div id="Link">
    main menu
    </div>
    </div>
<br> asdf </br>
<br> asdf </br>
<br> asdf </br>
<br> asdf </br>
<br> asdf </br>
<br> asdf </br>
<br> asdf </br>
<br> asdf </br>

</div>
```

But for good effect you must have to use js for change class just like above Karol's example

Comment: ty for everyone answer my question,...ty all